# Configure Jackson instead using DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE - not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I want to configure Jackson instead using DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE every time when I'm requesting a date for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "income")
  public ResponseEntity calculateIncome(
      @RequestParam(value = "companyName") String companyName,
      @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
      @RequestParam(value = "startDate") LocalDate startDate,
      @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
      @RequestParam(value = "endDate") LocalDate endDate
  )
```

I've already tried setup it in JacksonConfig

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

or

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

also

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

or

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
```

even in application.properties i tried

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=true
```

I'm using spring-boot wit following dependencies

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I just don't want to repeat over and over the same @DataTimeFormat
but without it, I'm still getting error:

**in IntelJ**

> 2018-03-01 15:35:05.539  WARN 8168 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request
>   element:
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-02-28'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [2018-02-28]

**Postman**

```
{
    "timestamp": 1519914905555,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-02-28'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-02-28]",
    "path": "/incVat"
}
```

or

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-03-01T15:36:44.823+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-02-28'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-02-28]",
    "path": "/incVat"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
I Have found the solution [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/parsing-of-localdate-query-parameters-in-spring-boot/)
It's all about a custom editor for `LocalDate` and implementation of `Formatter`

```
@Bean
  public Formatter<LocalDate> localDateFormatter() {
    return new Formatter<LocalDate>() {
      @Override
      public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
      }

      @Override
      public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale) {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(object);
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in your Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Primary // pay attention on this
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

And the Jackson2Json configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Jackson2JsonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonObjectMapper jackson2JsonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

If not work, try:

- to change the order of the import of `jsr310` dependency in the pom.xml.
- add in the properties file: `jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps = false`

I had weird problems trying to make this work too.

As a last option, you could migrate to [Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#jackson--json-support), because they flipped the Jackson configuration default to write JSR-310 dates as ISO-8601 strings.

Comment: Already tried it but now I did it again but still doesn't work ;(

Comment: You put the @Primary? You have other `ObjectMapper` or `Jackson2JsonObjectMapper` beans configured?

Comment: Yeah just like you said.
Everything is working when I'm adding `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)` every time before `@RequestParam` but repeating this like 20 times is just ridiculous ;p

Comment: @lukaszgo3 As a last option, you could migrate to Spring Boot 2.0, because they flipped the Jackson configuration default to write JSR-310 dates as ISO-8601 strings.

Comment: Thank for help @Dherik I've found another solution ;)

Comment: Please, share your solution :)

Comment: I've edited my question and the solution is at the end ;)

Comment: @lukaszgo3 thanks! You can answer your own question and mark it as the solution.